# How to Line Up Sub List Items Vertically in Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a CSS hover menu and all is working except that my sub menu seems to shift one of the menu items and they don't line up vertically. I've been toying with the CSS but can't seem to figure out which setting it is.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="/administration">Admin</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub 1</li>
            <li>Sub 2</li>
            <li>Sub 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS

```
.navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
}
.navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CC0000;
    margin-left: -77px;
}
.navigation ul ul li {
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

You can see this in action at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGZNqG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `padding-right` attribute from the `.navigation ul li:last-child`. Because you have given the other `li`s a padding of `10px` in `.navigation ul li` styles...

```css
.navigation {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.navigation a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.u-pull-right li:last-child {
  padding: 2px 0px 2px 10px;
}

#admin-list li{
  padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
}
.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
}
.navigation ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.navigation ul li.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navigation ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.navigation ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #CC0000;
  margin-left: -77px;
}
.navigation ul ul li {
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row navigation no-print">
  <ul class="u-pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Users</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li id="admin-list"><a href="/administration">Admin</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Sub 1</li>
        <li>Sub 2</li>
        <li>Sub 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That certainly fixed it, but is there a way for me to still remove the padding-right from the "Admin" <li> without using `.navigation ul li:last-child`?

Comment: Do you want to remove the `padding-right` only from the `Sub 3` menu item? Or do you want to remove it from all the Sub Menu items?

Comment: All sub menu items, but also from `<li><a href="/administration">Admin</a></li>`

Comment: I know I can just use an inline style on the `<li>` but was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Ah okay wait I will give it a try...!

Comment: I have edited the answer, so that the `Admin` list item will have no padding right, and the Sub Menu Items will also not have a `padding-right` of `10px`. For that to happen, you have to give an `id` to the `Admin` list. Hope this is ok.